# How to add item to an arraylist with object class in alphabetical order

Tags: java, arrays, file, object

So I have a "Directory class", a "Person object class" and a text file of names somewhere in the folder. I have already converted the txt file and stored it into an arraylist under my "Directory class". I made a method inside my directory class to search for a name in that list. Now I have to make another method to ask the user to input a name to add into the arraylist, if its there already then an appropriate message pops up, if not then I have to add the name in the correct place (alphabetical order). I am having trouble doing that. My code for the search name method is this:`

```
public int searchLastName(String lastName) {
    int i;
    boolean found = false;
    int index;

    i = 0;
    index = -1;

    while (i < persons.size() && !found) {
        if (lastName.equalsIgnoreCase (persons.get(i).getLastName())) {
            index = i;
            found = true;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return index;
}
```

And the method to add is this so far...:`

```
public void optionA() {
    Person one;
    String lastName;
    String firstName;
    String initial;
    String department;

    int telNum;
    int index;
    int size;


    System.out.println("Please enter a last name to add into directory");
    lastName = kbd.next();
    index = searchLastName(lastName);

    if (index < 0) {
        System.out.println("Please enter first name");
        firstName = kbd.next();

        System.out.println("Please enter initial");
        initial = kbd.next();

        System.out.println("Please enter department");
        department = kbd.next();

        System.out.println("Please enter local phone number");
        telNum = kbd.nextInt();

        one = new Person(lastName, firstName, initial, department, telNum);

        persons.add(one);

    }

}
```

This is the constructor for the Person object class: `}

```
public Person (String lastN, String firstN, String intl, String departm, int tel) {
    lastName = lastN;
    firstName = firstN;
    initial = intl;
    department = departm;
    telNum = tel;
}
```

Please help I've been stuck on this for hours...

Comment: Im just trying to add the name anywhere to the list as my first step before I try to add it in the right spot (alphabetical)

Comment: Do you have to use an array? To ensure uniqueness could you use a set?

Comment: Sadly I have to use an array D=

Comment: Just add to the end and then sort it using `Collections,sort`

Comment: I agree with @ScaryWombat, assuming that your array list will always be relatively small.

Comment: Assuming that `persons` is an arraylist of `person` objects you can not `add` a `String` , you need to create new `Person` and add the new Object to the arraylist.  Also, `persons.size();` will return the length of the arraylist **not** the index, so just add it to the end.  Also, `lastName = persons.get(size).setLastName(lastName);` does not make sense at all.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Ok, I created a new Person, how do I add it to the end of the list?

Comment: `persons.add(newPerson)`  If in doubt read the javadocs

Comment: @ScaryWombat thanks I re did my code as you said, now how do I use the Collections, sort to arrange it alphabetically?

Comment: see the answer below

Comment: @ScaryWombat I did Collections.sort(persons) and an error came up under sort (no suitable method found for sort)

Comment: Also I didnt use the code below, i used mine ubove

Comment: did you try searching for what this error means?  Unless you provide the relevant code (what is `persons`, how is your different to that below?) it is impossible to tell you want is wrong

Answer (score -1):

You can implement the comparable interface in your Directory class. The documentation is listed here: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html
This would require you to write a compareTo() method inside your Directory class that takes in two Person Objects as parameters and you can write your own code to compare them.

After you have done this, simply add the names into your ArrayList, and then after you have added all of the names call Collections.sort(*your list*);

This method would increase your efficiency as opposed to going through the arraylist each time when a new person is added.

Here is an example implementation of the compareTo Method.

```
public int compareTo(Person firPerson, Person secPerson) {
    if (firPerson.getLastName.compareTo(secPerson.getName()) < 0) {
        // The first person's lastname is in front of the second person's.   
        return -1;
    } else if (firPerson.getLastName.compareTo(secPerson.getName()) > 0) {
        return 1; // Second is in front of first
    } else {
        return 0; // The two names are the same. 
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried using this method but there is an error on the "0" saying "bad operand types for binary operator '<'

Comment: try `if (firPerson.getLastName.compareTo(secPerson.getName()) < 0) `

Comment: I apologize, the parenthesis was placed wrong. Scary Wombat is correct.